# ASP.Net Core me rechaza todos mis archivos estáticos

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft

no sé que está pasando, pero es terrible, al parecer asp, no encuntra mis archivos, imagenes , scripts, css ,etc. No me movido mi archivo de carpeta ni nada similar , de hecho encuentra algunos archivos que están en el mismo lugar (en el caso de las imagenes) que los que no encuentra y terminal no parece haber ningun error , ni en el mismo visual

Esta es mi terminarl
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

StartUp.cs

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{



    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        //app.UseHsts();

    }

   // app.Run(context => { throw new Exception("error"); });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar tal vez lo que esta tratando de hacer el exe? para saber de que forma lo estas tratando de hacer

Comment: estaba trabajando haciendo una función, que no tiene nada que ver con la config del app y derrepente pum!! no accede a los archivos dentro del mismo proyecto, ya cree un proyecto nuevo y me pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 1):

Estas agregando `app.UseStaticFiles()` en tu *Startup.cs* en el método `Configure`?

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: si si, ahorita lo agrego a la pregunta

Comment: Están marcados los archivos como 'Content' en el Build Action?

Comment: lo tengo en c# compiler el action build

Answer (score 1):

tuve el mismo problema lo soluciono agregando

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
```

en Startup.cs en el método Configure..
saludos